How to modify line breakers in styler package?
I would like to create a new style using the styler package that is equivalent to the Tidyverse style, with two exceptions: 1) There should always be a line break after the opening of a function call, and 2) there should always be a line break before the closing of a function call.
library(tidyverse)

# original
diamonds |>
  mutate(new = log(carat), sum = x + z, my_new_column = log(x)) |>
  filter(new < 3)

# desired format after formatting
diamonds |>
  mutate(
    new = log(carat),
    sum = x + z,
    my_new_column = log(x)
  ) |>
  filter(new < 3)

# Tidyverse style after formatting
diamonds |>
  mutate(new = log(carat),
         sum = x + z,
         my_new_column = log(x)) |>
  filter(new < 3)


It can't be that hard to achieve but after reading the docs I still couldn't get it to work. I have already put together something hacky using both the styler and rstudioapi packages but would prefer a proper style definition.
